# Regular Expression to validate any Hebrew year in the Hebrew Numeric System

Tags: regex, date, validation, hebrew

I need to validate input to make sure it's a valid Hebrew year number, which can only have certain valid sequences of letters.

Something like (pseudo regex) `([:thousands:]')?[:hundreds combinations:][:tens:]?("[:alef-tes digits:])?`
But then sometimes it's only single digits, or tens etc without any hundreds or thousands...

Not sure what it's formally called, the Hebrew Numeric system? Hebrew Numerology? Hebrew Numeral System? Gematria?
Overview described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_numerals
Test here: https://hebrewnumerals.github.io/
Examples:

- 1 = א
- 15 = ט"ו
- 16 = ט"ז
- 42 = מ"ב
- 133 = קל"ג
- 499 = תצ"ט
- 501 = תק"א
- 651 = תרנ"א
- 765 = תשס"ה
- 872 = תתע"ב
- 1015 = א׳ט"ו
- 1724 = א׳תשכ"ד
- 2389 = ב׳שפ"ט
- 4129 = ד׳קכ"ט
- 4487 = ד׳תפ"ז
- 6298 = ו׳רצ"ח
- 7892 = ז׳תתצ"ב
- 9301 = ט׳ש"א

Some examples of invalid year numbers:

- ז׳צת"ב (Taf 400 cannot be after Tzadik 90)
- שר"ו (Shin 300 followed by Resh 200 invalid, should have been Taf 400 followed by Kuf 100)
- פ'א"ב (Alef 1 followed by Bet 2 not ok, should be Gimmel 3)
- ל"מ bad - should've been ע
- ט"ט bad - should've been י"ח

(Tried searching for existing libraries or calendar source codes, gave regex101 a bunch of tries)

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: In this case PHP (though it would seem the regular expression solution would probably be useful in any language / tool)

Comment: What would be considered invalid input?

Comment: Good question, I should've provided a few examples:
- ז׳צת"ב (Taf 400 cannot be after Tzadik 90)
- שר"ו (Shin 300 followed by Resh 200 invalid, should have been Taf 400 followed by Kuf 100)
- פ'א"ב (Alef 1 followed by Bet 2 not ok, should be Gimmel 3)
- ט"ט invalid - should be י"ח

Comment: Obligatory "now you have two problems" comment (I post it so you don't have to).

Comment: There's a fair bit of work involved with making a regex here as it's almost into parsing territory. If you want an answer, please provide positive (that should match) and negative (that should not match) edge cases to make clear what you want and to facilitate testing for the generous souls who may answer. There are variants for some numbers, eg `15` may written as be `ט״ו` or `י״ה` - must all variants be supported? Please also correct errors in your examples, such as the use of a regular quote character `"` (hex `0022`) in your version of `15` instead of the correct `״` (hex `05f4`)

Answer (score 0):

PHP non-regex workaround I'm using for now:

1. Start with the reverse; Make a function `numberToHeb($num)` that reliably converts a number (ex 4345) into a properly formulated hebrew number (ד'שמ"ה). Currently making use of built in PHP calendar conversion functions taking advantage of the year number as a general purpose convert-number-to-hebrew functionality (limited to 1-9999 range)
2. Now make a function `hebNumber($str)` to take any hebrew number (ex ד'שמ"ה) wishing to be validated if it is a valid formulation of any hebrew number (1-9999 in this case). In this function;
3. Convert every hebrew digit to numerical value (ד'=4000, ש=300, מ=40, ה=5) add up the total (4345), pass the total thru the `numberToHeb($num)` function from step #1, check if the resulting string matches the string given to the `hebNumber($str)` function, If matches = passes validation, otherwise it was not a properly formed hebrew number.

```php
function numberToHeb(int $num){
    // limitation of using built in calendar converstion functions
    //  to convert number to hebrew representation: only handles 1-9999
    
    $x1 = mb_convert_encoding(
        jdtojewish(
            jewishtojd(1,1,$num), true,
            CAL_JEWISH_ADD_GERESHAYIM|CAL_JEWISH_ADD_ALAFIM_GERESH
        ),
        "UTF-8",
        "ISO-8859-8"
    );

    return mb_substr($x1, mb_strrpos($x1, ' ') + 1);

    // alternatively can port to PHP something like
    //    https://hebrewnumerals.github.io/ function Generate(...)
    // or https://github.com/MattMcManis/Aleph/blob/master/src/Aleph/Aleph/Converter.cs
}

function hebNumber(string $num){
    $lets = [
        // looks like StackOverflow code block reverses the text direction for RTL text, even the greater-than symbol looks like a less-than
        // but it's really "x" => N
        "א" => 1,
        "ב" => 2,
        "ג" => 3,
        "ד" => 4,
        "ה" => 5,
        "ו" => 6,
        "ז" => 7,
        "ח" => 8,
        "ט" => 9,
        "י" => 10,
        "כ" => 20,
        "ל" => 30,
        "מ" => 40,
        "נ" => 50,
        "ס" => 60,
        "ע" => 70,
        "פ" => 80,
        "צ" => 90,
        "ק" => 100,
        "ר" => 200,
        "ש" => 300,
        "ת" => 400,
    ];
    $parts = explode("'", $num); // if has thousands digit
    $main = end($parts);
    $total = 0;
    if (count($parts)>1) {
        // has thousands digit; add to total
        $yrpart = $parts[0];
        $main = $parts[1];
        $total = ($lets[$yrpart]??0) * 1000;
    }
    foreach (mb_str_split($main) as $char) {
        // simply add up each individual letter to total
        $total += $lets[$char] ?? 0;
    }

    // if valid hebrew input number, then input string should match same as generating the hebrew from total
    return numberToHeb($total) === $num ? $total : false;
}
```

```bash
>>> hebNumber("ד'שמ\"ה")
=> 4345
>>> hebNumber("ד'שה\"מ")
=> false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).